# Troubleshooting: Kernel always dies using IJulia in IPython notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, julia, ijulia-notebook

I recently began using julia, and I would like to use in with IPython Notebook/Jupyter.

So, I installed julia using MacPorts, i.e. `sudo port install julia`. Following the installation instructions here: https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl

After the prompt, I used `"Pkg.add("IJulia")` to install IJulia.

However, I cannot use Julia with IPython notebook. After opening the notebook with

```
ipython notebook --profile=julia
```

the kernel for the julia notebook dies instantly and cannot be restarted.

The error on the Terminal shows:

```
[I 19:03:19.410 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5)
WARNING:root:kernel dc00ae3a-8fa6-4d01-a802-f7845a16a9ba restarted
ERROR: SHA256 not defined
 in include at /opt/local/lib/julia/sys.dylib
 in process_options at /opt/local/lib/julia/sys.dylib
 in _start at /opt/local/lib/julia/sys.dylib
while loading /Users/NAME/.julia/v0.3/IJulia/src/kernel.jl, in expression starting on line 6
```

I suspect I have installed IJulia incorrectly? How can I solve this?

(The version of julia is `julia version 0.3.11`. The version of python is `Python 2.7.10`. The version of ipython is 4.0.0.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current stable version of Julia is v0.4.0.
You should download it directly from the Julia homepage (.dmg):

http://julialang.org/downloads/

Having done that, run it and do `Pkg.add("IJulia")` again.

Then from within Julia do

```
using IJulia
notebook()
```

Note that the Jupyter Notebook (the new name for what used to be the IPython Notebook) is run as

```
jupyter notebook
```

The `--profile julia` is no longer necessary and should be removed.

Furthermore, this (`jupyter notebook`) will only work if you had a previous installation of Jupyter, which seems to be the case. In this case, I suggest you upgrade it with `conda`, if you installed Anaconda, or with `pip`.)

Comment: Thank you for the help. I don't quite understand the last comment, ", I suggest you upgrade it with conda, if you installed Anaconda, or with pip.". 
Why should I try `conda update ipython` ?

Comment: Try `conda update conda` and `conda update ipython-notebook`.  Then from Julia do `Pkg.build("IJulia")` so that IJulia finds the new version of the notebook. Any luck?

Comment: I see what you're saying now. I used `pip install -U jupyter` Thanks! http://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html