# Julia Kernel for Jupyter crashes

Tags: julia, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I installed Julia but cannot run a notebook in Jupyter (XUbuntu 14.04). As soon as I start a new notebook, it connects with the kernel and then crashes:

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

There's 2 possible things that I can think of.
First, I installed Julia like this:

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:staticfloat/julianightlies
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:staticfloat/julia-deps
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install julia
```

and then:

```
julia> Pkg.add("IJulia")
julia> Pkg.build("IJulia")
```

when running `$ jupyter notebook`, it showed the messages above. I removed Julia and now I have version 0.4.6, which I can run perfectly from bash. It still crashes in Jupyter, though. And it still shows two versions of Julia:

[image]

(Python and R work just nice)

---

The second idea is, maybe it has something to do with being root? If I run

```
$ Julia
julia> using IJulia
ERROR: SystemError: opening file /home/luis/.julia/lib/v0.4/IJulia.ji: Permission denied
 in open at ./iostream.jl:90
 in open at iostream.jl:102
 in stale_cachefile at loading.jl:439
 in recompile_stale at loading.jl:474
 in _require_from_serialized at loading.jl:83
 in _require_from_serialized at ./loading.jl:109
 in require at ./loading.jl:235
```

If I run:

```
$ sudo Julia
julia> using IJulia
```

it throws no errors at all.

---

Any ideas what could be happening?

Note: I am aware of [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35195061/kernel-error-in-ijulia-notebook-failed-to-start-the-kernel-in-jupyter?rq=1) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33589789/776515) here, but they havn't worked for me...

Comment: `/home/luis/.julia/lib/v0.4/IJulia.ji: Permission denied` - all the files in `/home/luis` should belong to your user and have at least user read permissions. I'd guess that `chown -R luis /home/luis/.julia` will solve this issue.

Comment: @cel That did the trick, neat and directly. You mind to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can happen when files in your home directory were created by root and thus do not belong to your user. Rule of thumb is here: everything in your home directory should to belong to your user account.

You can use `chown` to change ownership:

`sudo chown -R luis /home/luis/.julia` will recursively change the owner of all files in `/home/luis/.julia` to the user account `luis`.